# FreeGLUT 3.0.0 Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, glut, freeglut

Where is the Visual Studio solution for FreeGLUT 3.0.0?  I know the 2.8.1 has one, but 3.0.0 does not.  I would really like to use the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

[Use the included CMakeLists.txt to create a Visual Studio solution:](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/README.cmake)

> ### How to build freeglut with CMake on Windows (MS Visual Studio)
>
> 1. Download CMake (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html).
>      Get one of the releases from the binary distribution section.
> 2. Run the CMake installer, install wherever you like.
> 3. Launch CMake via Start > Program Files > CMake 2.8 > CMake (GUI)
>      (note that the shortcut put by the installer on your desktop does NOT
>      point to the CMake GUI program!)
> 4. In the "Where is the source code" box, type or browse to the root
>      directory of your freeglut source (so that's /freeglut, not
>      /freeglut/src).
> 5. In the "Where to build the binaries" box, type or browse to any
>      folder you like - this will be where the Visual Studio solution will be
>      generated. This folder does not have to exist yet.
> 6. Hit the Configure button near the bottom of the window.
> 7. Pick your target compiler, make sure that its installed on your
>      system of course!
> 8. Answer Ok when asked if you want to create the build directory.
> 9. Wait for the configure process to finish.
> 10. The screen will now have some configuration options on it, for
>       instance specifying whether you want to build static and/or shared
>       libraries (see below for a complete list). When you've selected your
>       options, click the Configure button again.
> 11. The Generate button at the bottom will now be enabled. Click Generate.
> 12. The build files will now be generated in the location you picked.
>
> You can now navigate to the build directory you specified in step 5.
>   Open the freeglut.sln file that was generated in your build directory,
>   and compile as usual